# window moving after setSize on JFrame when setResizable is false

Tags: java, swing

When I check the documentation of Frame.setResizable, i read:

```
Sets whether this frame is resizable by the user.
```

So I understand that I can still call setSize on it to programatically resize it. But if I do so, the Frame moves down ! (At least under Ubuntu, Unity). This is especially annoying if I want the frame to match the size of the content. For instance, just try the following SSCCE :

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("test");
                mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                mainFrame.setResizable(false);
                final JTextArea field = new JTextArea() {
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        Dimension pref = super.getPreferredSize();
                        return new Dimension(Math.max(50, pref.width),Math.max(20, pref.height));
                    }
                };
                ((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
                        System.out.println("before "+mainFrame.getLocation().y);
                        mainFrame.pack();
                        System.out.println("after "+mainFrame.getLocation().y+"\n");
                    }
                });
                mainFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                mainFrame.getContentPane().add(field,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                mainFrame.pack();
                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Type some characters to make the window extend. At least on Unity, the window moves down the screen... I don't know how to work around this.

UPDATE :

The result of the above code is as follow :

```
before 52
after 52

before 80
after 108

before 108
after 108

before 136
after 136

before 164
after 164

before 192
after 192
...
```

In the end, I don't get when the Frame is being moved...

This is the stacktrace I can get if I add a ComponentListener on my Frame :

```
at test.Test2$1$3.componentMoved(Test2.java:50)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentMoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:169)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.componentMoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:169)
at java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6345)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6296)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2022)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:77)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:77)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

It behave as if I was manually moving the frame. It is probably Unity doing something when the Frame is resized.

Comment: If all you want is to have the frame match the preferred size of its contents, then all you have to do is call mainFrame.pack() instead of trying to reset its size yourself.

Comment: Remember, there is a difference between the frame size and the content size, the intention is the frame will "wrap" around the content, so the frame should always be larger than the content

Comment: Thanks, I used pack at first, but I wanted to make clear that it was the `setSize` operation that was causing trouble. I have the same problem with pack.

Answer (score 3):

> just try the following SSCCE :

It is not a SSCCE (close but not quite). There is no main() method and no imports. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test without any thinking.

> Type some characters to make the window extend

Works fine for me using JDK8 on Windows 7.

```
//mainFrame.setSize(mainFrame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize());
mainFrame.pack();
```

I would use the above code. You will get a better sizing of the frame, since the `pack()` will take into account the frame decorations unlike the setSize() method.

If the `pack()` doesn't fix the problem then I guess the suggestion would be to save the location of the frame first and then invoke the `setLocation(...)` method, or use `setBounds(...)` to fully control the size/location.

Edit:

> In the end, I don't get when the Frame is being moved...

Try something like this:

```
((AbstractDocument)field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter()
{
    @Override
    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException
    {
        Point location = mainframe.getLocation();

        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);

        mainFrame.pack();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                mainframe.setLocation( location );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, my first code was using `mainFrame.pack();` but I changed it to make more clear that it is the setSize that generates the issue. Sorry for the SSCCE... About your solution, if only if was that easy. I updated my question.

Comment: 1) That is not how you set the size of the frame. As you were told in the first 2 comments and my answer, the size of the content pane is not the same as the size of the frame. 2) see my edit.

Comment: The size of the Frame is not the issue here. I will use pack if it is too confusing. Whatever, it doesn't change the fact that the window is moving down. Your solution is nice, but the interruption comes generally after the invokeLater unfortunately...

Comment: `I will use pack if it is too confusing.` - pack() is the proper solution. Using setSize() is the wrong approach since your posted code does NOT take into account the frame decorations which means the text is not fully contained in the window which is the goal of your question. The code you post in the forum should demonstrate your requirement!!! `but the interruption comes generally after the invokeLater unfortunately` - then you platform is doing something strange. Unless you can identify when/how this code is invoked you won't be able to solve your problem.

Comment: The test case was there to show an issue, not to achieve a goal. Of course I would use pack if it was my real code. I just wanted to isolate the part which is buggy. setSize will directly call setBounds whereas pack will do some other stuff before. Yeah, I agree, my platform is probably acting weird. The event appears directly in the pump so I guess that it doesn't come from Java. What I think is that Java request the frame to be at a specific location, and then the platform moves the frame down to add the decoration.